# How do I split repeated blocks of data into multiple columns and parse datetime?

Tags: python, file, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.read_table('151101.mnd',header = 30)
print f.head()
print f.shape


                    2015-11-01 00:10:00 00:10:00
0  #    z  speed    dir      W   sigW       bck  error
1      30   5.05  333.0   0.23   0.13  1.44E+05   0.00
2      40   5.05  337.1  -0.02   0.14  7.69E+03   0.00
3      50   5.03  338.5   0.00   0.15  4.83E+03   0.00
4      60   6.21  344.3  -0.09   0.18  6.13E+03   0.00

(4607, 1)
```

Basically I have this file that I read in with pandas. There is 2 things that I would like to do.

1. I would like to store the `Time` header as a variable called time. The tricky part of this is that every 33 rows another block of data starts with the next 10 min in the day's data. So I guess every 33 rows I would need to grab the `Time` header and store it as the variable time.
2. When I print out the shape of the file it says there are `4,607 rows` and 1 column. However I would like to split this "one column of text" into 8 columns. `index`, `z`, `speed`, `dir`, `w`, `sigw`, `bck`, `error`.

How do I accomplish these two things?

Comment: Can you add a segment of your data file to the post? I think it is likely that read_table is not correctly parsing your data file. I've had troubles with read_table myself, and it is common to have issues with it. It might help to use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: I have also tried read_csv and it works the same way. I tried numpy.loadtxt but I get an error with my file name: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-11-01. Also what do you mean by add a segment of my data file to the post? I have the first 4 rows of the data file included in my post. Could you be more specific on what else I could include that would help you?

Comment: It appears that what is posted is the dataframe, which may have different formatting from the actual data file. It's always best to show the raw data for these types of things, so that people can run some code to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if each 33rd line is filled by date, you need parse each 32 rows by function [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_table.html).

Then data are filtered, because headers of data are between data by function [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html).

Second part parse dates to dataframe `df1`. I specify three column by parameter `names` and then parse datetime to one column `Datetime` by `parse_dates`.

Then data are filtered by function [str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to dataframe `df1`.

All indexes are reset by function [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#parse data to dataframe df
df = pd.read_table('test/151101.mnd', 
                   sep = '\s+', 
                   header=None, 
                   skiprows = np.arange(0 , 4608, 32),
                   names=['i','z','speed','dir','W','sigW','bck','error','tmp'],
                   usecols=['i','z','speed','dir','W','sigW','bck','error']
                    )

df = df[~df['W'].isin(['dir'])].reset_index(drop=True)
print df.head()

#parse date to df1
df1 = pd.read_table('test/151101.mnd', 
                   sep = '\s+', 
                   names=['d1','d2','d3'],
                   parse_dates={"Datetime" : [0, 1, 2]}
                     )
print df1.head()   

df1 = df1[df1['Datetime'].str.contains(":")].reset_index(drop=True)          
print df1.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Case ( 1 ) rows repeat themselves at the same step

---

```
pd.read_table(sep = '\s+', skiprows = np.arange(0 , 4607, 32))
```

### Case ( 2 ) the unwanted rows appear randomly

---

if not so you've to remove it manually , so you need first to load your data into single column

```
df = pd.read_table()
```

then you need to detect the unwanted columns by doing the following

```
indices_to_remove = df.iloc[: , 0].str.contains('^\s*\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}')
```

then slice only the needed columns

```
df[~indices_to_remove]
```

then finally create your final `dataframe`

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df[~indices_to_remove].iloc[: , 0].str.split('\s+')))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful in my splitting the data into columns! Now my only problem is that I want to delete every 30 rows because there is a time header every 30 rows. So if you have a suggestion for this that would be great! But you solved half of my problem!

Comment: is the position of this row variant ? or at the same step for every 30 rows

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the `2015-11-01 00:10:00 00:10:00` row from your file, because it causes `pandas` to perceive it as a column header, dumping everything below into column with that name.

Comment: Ok so I decided to get rid of the time header as suggested but then every 30 or so rows there is another time header. How do I tell it to delete every 30 rows so that I can just have the columns of data? Opening the file and manually deleting them isn't an option for me since I have a ton of files to loop through eventually.

Comment: You need to parse your file with a script that will do that for you before processing it, because unfortunately `pandas` won't handle loading inconsistent file.